# Where would the centre of gravity be for 4D shapes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, geometry

Say, hypothetically, we took a hypersphere where would the centre of gravity be for such an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would reside in the center of mass of the 4d shape. Like it would be in all dimensions. For a 4d hyperspherical mass distribution this would be the point in the center of the sphere.